# Extracting the resource method name from JAX-RS ContainerRequestFilter & ContainerResponseFilter

Tags: jax-rs

I have a Filter class

```
    @Provider
    @PreMatching
    @Priority(1700)
    A_authenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter 
    {
    try {
            // Logic
            }
    catch {
        throw Exception
    }
    }
```

Another Filter class

```
    @Provider
    @PreMatching
    @Priority(5000)
    B_authenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter,ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Context
    ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) { }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext { }


    }
```

A Controller class
//JAX-RS controller

```
    @Path
    TokenServicesImpl {

    @POST
    @Path
    public Response login() {
    }

    }
```

What happens is When I want to call login of Controller class it goes through 1st A_authenticationFilter and it fails due to some validation error in headers, therefore login method doesn't get executed and 
resourceInfo.getResourceMethod() resolves to be null in B_authenticationFilter's filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext).

I suppose resourceInfo gets populated only when the controller method get executed. If login method is not executed then is there any other way though which I can get populated resourceInfo object with resource method name i.e. 'login' in it?

Comment: Can you please add some code in explaining your problem. Thanks. And also try to elaborate a little more. Assume we know nothing about your code, reread your question a few times, and try to fill in all the holes you think we would need to know to help you out.

Comment: @Paul Samsotha Sorry for the unclear question. here is a more descriptive one

Answer (score 0):

Remove the [`@PreMatching`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/container/PreMatching.html) annotation from your filter if you want to use [`ResourceInfo`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/container/ResourceInfo.html). From the [`@PreMatching`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/container/PreMatching.html) documentation:

> The JAX-RS runtime will apply the filters marked with the `@PreMatching` annotation globally to all resources, before the incoming request has been matched to a particular resource method. [...]

Once the request has not been matched to any resource method yet, this information is unavailable.